# In assembly, I want to search a string, replace a word, and display the new string

Tags: string, assembly, x86

I am taking an assembly course and I have gotten most of the program written out, I am just having trouble replacing the word and displaying the new string.  The problem asks for a sentence, a word to find, and a word to replace it with.  The program scans the string, replaces any instances of the word, and shows you the new string.
Example:  "The sky is blue."
Word to find: "sky"
Word to replace it: "ocean"
New String:  "The ocean is blue."

Here is what I have so far:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA
prompt1 BYTE    "String to Search: ", 0
prompt2 BYTE    "Word to Search For: ", 0
prompt3 BYTE    "Word to replace with: ", 0
target  BYTE    80 DUP (?)
key     BYTE    80 DUP (?)
strSub  BYTE    80 DUP (?)
trgtLength  DWORD   ?
keyLength   DWORD   ?
lastPosn    DWORD   ?
strSubLen   DWORD   ?
resultLbl BYTE  "The new sentence is: ", 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
    input prompt1, target, 80   ;input target string
    lea eax, target             ;address of target
    push eax                    ;parameter
    call strlen                 ;strlen(target)
    add esp, 4                  ;remove parameter
    mov trgtLength, eax         ;save length of target
    input prompt2, key, 80      ;input key string
    lea eax, key                ;address of key
    push eax                    ;parameter
    call strlen                 ;strlen(key)
    add esp, 4                  ;remove parameter
    mov keyLength, eax          ;save length of key
    input prompt3, strSub, 80   ;input word to search for
            lea eax, strSub             ;address of key
    push eax                    ;parameter
    call strlen                 ;strlen(strSub)
    add esp, 4                  ;remove parameter
    mov strSubLen, eax          ;save length of key

    mov eax, trgtLength
    sub eax, keyLength
    inc eax                     ;trgtLength - keyLength +1
    mov lastPosn, eax
    cld                         ;Left to Right comparison
    mov eax, 1                  ;starting position

    whilePosn:
        cmp eax, lastPosn       ;position <= last_posn?
        jnle endWhilePosn       ;exit if past last position

        lea esi, target         ;address of target string
        add esi, eax            ;add position
        dec esi                 ;address of position to check
        lea edi, key            ;address of key
        mov ecx, keyLength      ;number of position to check
        repe cmpsb              ;check
        jz found                ;exit of success
        inc eax                 ;increment position
        jmp whilePosn           ;repeat

    endWhilePosn:
        output resultLbl, [esi] ;display new sentence
        jmp quit

    found:
        sub edi, keyLength
        mov ecx, strSubLen
        lea esi, strSub
        cld
        rep movsb
        inc eax
        jmp whilePosn

    quit:
        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP


strlen  PROC
push ebp                    ;establish stack frame
mov ebp, esp
push ebx                    ;save EBX
sub eax, eax                ;length := 0
mov ebx, [ebp+8]            ;address of string

whileChar:
cmp BYTE PTR [ebx], 0       ;null byte?
je endWhileChar             ;exit if so
inc eax                     ;increment length
inc ebx                     ;point at next character
jmp whileChar               ;repeat

endWhileChar:
pop ebx                     ;restore registers
pop ebp
ret
strlen  ENDP
END
```

The code works as far as finding the word that I want to switch, but actually switching the words is tricking me up.  The book says that the destination string should be in EDI and the word to replace should be in ESI, but the code they give as an example has the destination string in ESI, and word to replace in EDI (like I have here).

The book also does a pretty horrible job of explaining the "rep" and "movs" instructions, so I am 90% sure that my "found" code block is going to be where the problem is.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can swap the registers temporarily with `xchg edi, esi`; or you could opt for a completely different register allocation. Nothing dictates e.g. to use 'ecx' as a counter (unless you need to use rep xxxx instructions, or loop).

Comment: There are many approaches to this, some are fast, some are simple. Inserting strings in strings is neither, and in-loop case sensitive compare is slow. It's possible to write elegant solutions in Assembler as in any language. Think about what could be simpler or faster. In this case, perhaps split words into a string array, easily compare, and a quick and easy join when done? Another approach is putting marker bytes for matching characters and skip over those when you join. Assembler has all the possibilities for reinventing a better wheel. ;)

Comment: I don't know x86 at all, but it looks like you don't insert/delete chars if strlen(search)!=strlen(replace). Also, you need to skip strlen(search) chars, not just 1 char, when found (eax). (Example: replace 'xx' with 'xxx'.) You should still get some output, what is the output? Have you single-stepped through the code and watched the register values?

Comment: Having had more time to go over and thanks to @Perror's second link, I think I have narrowed down my problem a little better

As it is right now, the program searches the `target` for the `key` byte by byte.  Once the `key` is found it jumps to the `found code block`, and then using the `stosb` it tries to copy the `strSub` into the `taregt`.  The problem is that it's only copying the first letter of `strSub`, and it copies it backwards over the part of the string I want to save.

Comment: Okay, so I edited the `found code block` to what I have now, and I have figured out that by changing `stosb` to and `movsb` and adjusting my esi and edi pointers, it copies the whole string over, not just one letter.

Also, the program isn't copying backwards so much as its copying over the beginning of the string.  Like it doesn't start copying where the program found the `key`.

Comment: Looks like with a little help from @perror I was able to answer my own question.  I have the updated my `found` code block to show the changes.

By using `movsb` instead of `stosb` and altering the address of `edi` by the `keyLength`, I was able to copy over the piece of string that I was aiming for.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with strings in x86 assembly, one has to quickly master the `rep` instruction. If not, you will probably pass away before your first program has been completed.

A very good introduction on string manipulation in assembly can be found [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228774-masm-using-string-instructions/) (or [here](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Windows/HTML/StringInstructions.html)), but what you really need here are the following ones:

- [`rep stosb`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/stosb.htm): Store string
- [`rep scas`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/scas.htm): Scan string
- [`rep cmpsb`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/cmpsb.htm): Compare string

Comment: Your second link was very helpful in explaining the above instructions.  I realized that I was going about it from the wrong angle.  I am still having problems with my program, but so far you've provided the most help.  Thank you.

Comment: `repe`/`repne`-string instructions are are for explicit-length strings where you already know the `strlen`.  And on current CPUs, they're not faster than byte-at-a-time loops.  (Only rep movs/stos memcpy / memset are fast.)